# Using after_action callback for ActionMailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

I recently discovered the after_action callback for ActionMailer and it's helping clean up a lot of code! The problem I am having is the callback is not executed until after the email is rendered. This makes it so you can't instantiate any variables for use in the view.

So for example, lets say that all of the emails in my mailer needs to include an unsubscribe link for the user:

```
class BaseMailer < ActionMailer::Base

  def email1(user)
    @user = user
    include_unsubscribe_link
    ...
  end

  def email2(user)
    @user = user
    include_unsubscribe_link
    ...
  end

  #...more actions

  private

  def include_unsubscribe_link
    headers['List-Unsubscribe'] = @unsubscribe_link = @user.unsubscribe_link
  end
end
```

It would be great to clean this up with an after_action, but the callback is run after the view is rendered so the view can't access the instance variable. I can't use a before_action because the instance variable isn't instantiated yet and depends on the parameters of the action.

Any way to DRY this up?

Answer (score 0):

You can DRY it up using `default`:

```
class BaseMailer < ActionMailer::Base

  default 'List-Unsubscribe' => proc { @user.unsubscribe_link }

  def email1(user)
    @user = user
    ...
    mail
  end

  def email2(user)
    @user = user
    ...
    mail
  end

  #...more actions
```

`default` hash allows using a proc, which will be evaluated when you call `mail` method, which is perfect in your case. I would also suggest not assigning `@unsubscribe_link` as instance variable. Since you are already passing `@user` it is completely obsolete and the less instance variables you share with the view the better,